# How to remove character in csv file using spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a csv file with the following data and header:

age;"job";"marital status"; (as header)
58;"technician";"married; (values)

How can I remove the double quotes at the beginning and replace it with blanks?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Do you mean, you want the first row to become `age;job;marital status;`?

Comment: Yes, please. The quotes are not regular. 
It shows up as age;"job""| as a single column, the rest of the columns have two quotes ""marital status"". I don't know what I need to do to remove all the quotes and also to separate age and job as they get smooshed together into a single column.